# Limit for using Speech to Text free tier

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the free tier Speech to Text service in order to convert wav file into text. When I try to convert several wav files (which is about 2 min long each) in sequence I get the following error.

```
Status: Canceled. Reason: The recognition service encountered an internal error and could not continue.Respones text:{"Duration":0,"Offset":0,"RecognitionStatus":"Error"}.
```

I can use the API again after waiting for few minutes. It looks like there is some kind of limit or quota when you use the free tier. Are there any documents that explains the limits of the free tier for Speech to Text services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free tier allows you to transcribe 5 hours, 5,000 transactions per month, 20 per minute.

Answer (score 0):

In addition there is a limit on simultaneous connections for free subscriptions (2? - not sure) and for the paid subscriptions (that can be adjusted). As files might get transcribed faster than real-time, you could run into the simultaneous connection limit (that it works after a delay is another indication here)

Wolfgang